# How to debug php code in this case?

Tags: php, android

I 'm developing an android app which connects to database using PHP API. It's the first time for me to encounter PHP.
What happens is that I "POST" parameters to the php code with a URL to connect to  it then php makes a query to my database and store them ... the issue is that all I see is what happens in logcat, I have no idea what is goin on with the PHP so if there is something wrong in there what can I do to debug it ?

Note : I 'm already familiar with echos and var dump I 'm looking for fully debugging tool that will allow me to debug the script without actually running it directly and by that I mean accessing it from my android project.

Comment: Where is the php code ?

Comment: What do you need it for ?

Comment: You asking how to debug php without seeing it ?

Comment: I 'm asking if there is a tool to debug PHP code while accessing it remotely from android project ... sorry if there is a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases i log / append all actions on php side into a file - with a simple

> file_put_contents({file}, {data}, FILE_APPEND);

.
u could also catch nearly every error in php with following methods:

```
set_error_handler({YOUR_ERROR_HANDLER}, E_ALL);

register_shutdown_function({YOUR_ERROR_HANDLER});
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.register-shutdown-function.php

example code of how would i test an envoirement in php, which i could not debug direct:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// will be triggered on every php shutdown - will log the last error (if one occurs)
register_shutdown_function(function()
{
    // get last error
    $aError = error_get_last();

    if(!empty($aError))
    {
        logAction('called from register_shutdown_function | ' . $aError['message']);
    }
});

// will be triggered on every error
set_error_handler(function($iErrCode, $sErrorText, $sErrorFile = '', $sErrorLine = '')
{
    logAction('called from set_error_handler | Code: ' . $iErrCode . ' Text: ' . $sErrorText . ' File: ' . $sErrorFile . ' Line: ' . $sErrorLine);
}, E_ALL);

// will be triggered on every exception
set_exception_handler(function(\Exception $e)
{
    logAction('called from set_exception_handler | Code: ' . $e->getCode() . ' Text: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' File: ' . $e->getFile() . ' Line: ' . $e->getLine());
});

// main log / debug method
function logAction($sText)
{
    $sDate = date('Y.m.d H:i:s');
    file_put_contents('debug.log', $sDate . ': ' . $sText, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: BTW, the ops needs to debug from android project it seems !

Comment: Sorry I 'm new to PHP so if you can elaborate more with an example it will be much appreciated